# reactjs forceUpdating another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been using redux .. i am changing state tree using using redux actions ...

sometimes updating the state does not refresh the component .. i have to force update by this.forceUpdate() .. why is this happening? Under what condition does this happen.. usually updating state tree using an action automatically refreshes the component but sometimes it does not.. another question is that what if the state change needs to re-render a different component ?? how to i force update other components from another component ??﻿

Comment: Add the code where you're changing the state. You shouldn't need to change the state of a component from the state of other components, the parent class should take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure what your return *new* object from your reducers?
If your return the same object (only mutated) redux does not understand what data has changed.

If you need rerender component when data change that that component should be dependent on these data. `forceUpdate` is a really bad practice.

Comment: Thank you so much .. this was the problem . I did not know this .. returning new object solved the problem .. can't thank you enough, I was stuck here for days ...